# Query MySQL field for LIKE string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field called 'areasCovered' in a MySQL database, which contains a string list of postcodes.

There are 2 rows that have similar data e.g:

```
Row 1: 'B*,PO*,WA*'
Row 2: 'BB*, SO*, DE*'
```

*Note - The strings are not in any particular order and could change depending on the user*

Now, if I was to use a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM technicians WHERE areasCovered LIKE '%B*%'
```

I'd like it to return JUST Row 1. However, it's returning Row 2 aswell, because of the BB* in the string.

How could I prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 4):

The key to using `like` in this case is to include delimiters, so you can look for delimited values:

```
SELECT *
FROM technicians
WHERE concat(', ', areasCovered, ', ') LIKE '%, B*, %'
```

In MySQL, you can also use `find_in_set()`, but the space can cause you problems so you need to get rid of it:

```
SELECT *
FROM technicians
WHERE find_in_set('B', replace(areasCovered, ', ', ',') > 0
```

Finally, though, you should not be storing these types of lists as strings.  You should be storing them in a separate table, a junction table, with one row per technician and per area covered.  That makes these types of queries easier to express and they have better performance.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching wild cards at the start as well as end.

You need only at end.

```
SELECT * FROM technicians WHERE areasCovered LIKE 'B*%'
```

[Reference:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_not-like)

Comment: But if the B* was in the middle of the string, it wouldn't find it? The order of the strings are not in alphabetic order. So it could be: 'DE*, B*, SO*'

Answer (score 1):

Normally I hate REGEXP. But ho hum:

```
SELECT * FROM technicians 
WHERE concat(",",replace(areasCovered,", ",",")) regexp ',B{1}\\*';
```

To explain a bit:

**Get rid of the pesky space:**

```
select replace("B*,PO*,WA*",", ",",");
```

**Bolt a comma on the front**

```
select concat(",",replace("B*,PO*,WA*",", ",","));
```

**Use a REGEX to match "comma B once followed by an asterix":**

```
select concat(",",replace("B*,PO*,WA*",", ",",")) regexp ',B{1}\\*';
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not check it on my machine, but it's should work:

```
SELECT * FROM technicians WHERE areasCovered <> replace(areaCovered,',B*','whatever')
```

In case the 'B*' does not exist, the areasCovered will be equal to replace(areaCovered,',B*','whatever'), and it will reject that row.
In case the 'B*' exists, the areCovered will NOT be eqaul to replace(areaCovered,',B*','whatever'), and it will accept that row.

Answer (score -1):

You can Do it the way Programming Student suggested

`SELECT * FROM technicians WHERE areasCovered LIKE 'B*%'`

Or you can also use limit on query

`SELECT * FROM technicians WHERE areasCovered LIKE '%B*%' LIMIT 1`

Answer (score -1):

`%B*%` contains % on each side which makes it to return all the rows where value contains `B*` at any position of the text however your requirement is to find all the rows which contains values starting with `B*` so following query should do the work.

`SELECT * FROM technicians WHERE areasCovered LIKE 'B*%'`